# Bash script for logging in ftp

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp

I have seen this question: [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20560/is-there-a-way-to-write-a-script-to-do-ftp-login-so-i-dont-have-to-type-things)

I have similar, if not the same request. I'd like to create a script that will log me in ftp server. I do not want to automate the whole exchange, I just want to speed up the login. Security is not an issue, it can be most insecure way of doing it, I don't care, I doubt anyone would try to access the server, and even if someone does, I still don't care. =)

I have tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash
ftp -n ftp.domain.com
quote USER user
quote PASS pass
```

It seems to log me in successfully, but when I try to issue a new command I get:

```
530 You aren't logged in
ftp: bind: Address already in use
```

Answer (score 0):

try putting

```
machine ftp.domain.com
login user
passwod pass
```

in .netrc in your home dir.